# Reusable images question

Tags: entities, media

I want to have reusable images in my new Drupal 8 blog.

I followed [this guide](https://www.annertech.com/blog/reusable-media-drupal-8-tutorial) that uses the *Media Entity* and *Media Entity Image*   modules, but I have a problem every time I want to use an existing image. I get the following error.

> The referenced entity (media: 206) does not exist.

So far, I used the default field_image field in the articles, but now I want to use the new field_reusable_image that uses existing images.

Will the already uploaded images in field_image be available to be added in field_reusable_image?

Comment: Don't know if it is related but my blog often returns this error:

User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: media in drupal_get_filename() (line 250 of core/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created a field in media bundles that didn't match with the one in the content type.
The guide that I followed was not so clear so in the media bundle I created a field_image and I was trying to reference it with content.field_reusable_image in content type, which apparently didn't work.

Comment: Not 100% sure for my last comment that this solved the problem.

Comment: You have to create a field that references Media.

Comment: I already created a field_reusable_image in content type and referenced it to Media bundle field_image. I thought that they should have same name but doesn't make sense.